# What is the use of Cygwin exactly?

Tags: c++, path, directory, cygwin

I installed Cygwin on my laptop. After going through the instructions on netbeans site, i found that i need to change the path directory.

My path directory initially shows some java thing on that and if i change it then will it create some problem?

***I basically Want to run C/C++ programs by NetBeans so I installed Cygwin thinking that it would help me. 
Please Suggest me what to do.***

Comment: Is your question "What is the use of cygwin?", "If I change my path directory then will it create some problems?", or "Please suggest what I should do with cygwin installed?"

Comment: Give MinGW a shot.

Comment: @Eddge u got that write. I want to know answers to all these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Took this from the original [guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygwin-ug-net.pdf)

> Cygwin is a Linux-like environment for Windows. It consists of a DLL
>   (cygwin1.dll), which acts as an emulation layer providing substantial
>   POSIX (Portable Operating System Interface) system call functionality,
>   and a collection of tools, which provide a Linux look and feel. The
>   Cygwin DLL works with all x86 and AMD64 versions of Windows NT since
>   Windows XP SP3. The API follows the Single Unix Specification as much
>   as possible, and then Linux practice. The major differences between
>   Cygwin and Linux is the C library (newlib instead of glibc). With
>   Cygwin installed, users have access to many standard UNIX utilities.
>   They can be used from one of the provided shells such as bash or from
>   the Windows Command Prompt. Additionally, programmers may write Win32
>   console or GUI applications that make use of the standard Microsoft
>   Win32 API and/or the Cygwin API. As a result, it is possible to easily
>   port many significant UNIX programs without the need for extensive
>   changes to the source code. This includes configuring and building
>   most of the available GNU software (including the development tools
>   included with the Cygwin distribution).

---